# Complete WPF Timeline control for steady recording?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, timing, video-recording

I want to record a complex animated WPF application. The application has the ability to save Screenshots. I want to save a Screenshot exactly each 1/60 second. It does not have to run in realtime, but saving each frame takes longer than 1/60 second, and even if there was a method to save frames fast enough I'd like some very steady timing.

So my question is, is it possible to handle global App-Timer with code, for example on a CompositionTarget.Rendering Event, and advancing the time by hand - so the whole Application (or at least the WPF-XAML-animation-system) thinks an exact time passed?

Comment: i found this, maybe something alike: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748938(v=vs.110).aspx